# How to read an irregular xml string after change it to stream in C#

Tags: c#

How to read an irregular xml string after change it to stream in C#?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
string modoEntrada = "01";
string xml= "";

xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
xml += "<Transaccion xmlns=\"http://www.prosa.com.mx/xsd/\">";
//xml = "<Transaccion>";
xml += "<autorizacionRequest>";
xml += "<modoEntrada>" + modoEntrada + "</modoEntrada>"; //target
xml += "</autorizacionRequest>";
xml += "</Transaccion>";
xml.Replace(" ","_");

byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(stream);
XmlNode x = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/autorizacionRequest/modoEntrada");
```

The Problem is: `x == null`

It works with `<Transaccion>` instead of `<Transaccion xmlns="http://www.prosa.com.mx/xsd">`.

Comment: More words can also help people better help, you . Show the actual error you are getting.Explain my friend, explain :)

Comment: 1) don't use strings to create XML. 2) if you do anyway, use a StringBuilder. 3) With `XmlDocument.LoadXml()` you don't need to mess with Streams or Encodings. 4) Use XDocument instead of XmlDocument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Token** is a string which I was looking for:

```
switch (Token)
{

   case "modoEntrada":

      Regex exp_01 = new Regex("<descripcion>(?<arg>[A-Z]+)?</descripcion>");             
      m = exp_01.Match(InputText);
      break;

   case "descripcionRechazo":

      Regex exp_02 = new Regex("<descripcionRechazo>(?<arg>[A-Z ]+)?</descripcionRechazo>");
      m = exp_02.Match(InputText);
      break;
   ...
}

if (m.Success)
   ret = m.Groups["arg"].Value;
else
   ret = "";

return ret;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a [namespacemanager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) and use it in your xpath

```
  XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmldoc.Load(stream);

  var xmlNsM = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
  xmlNsM.AddNamespace("tr", @"http://www.prosa.com.mx/xsd/");

  XmlNode x = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/tr:Transaccion/tr:autorizacionRequest/tr:modoEntrada", xmlNsM );
```